# Powershell script to get csv file with file name and file size for a folder

Tags: powershell, csv

I have folder and there are sub folders in it. I need **file name** and **size** in the csv for all the files in the folder.

Comment: What have you tried and how did that differ from what you expected? Did you get any error messages? Please edit your question to include the code you are working with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code should work for you

```
$Directory = "C:\path to directory"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force | ForEach {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Size = "$([int]($_.length / 1mb)) MB"
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "./temp.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Any way to expand this to get the full path? I see it in the embedded "versionInfo" object in get-childitem -format-list, but extracting that seems a bit weird...